# Grant manage permission rights only without full control

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to grant people somehow rights to manage authorizations for a site, but not able to change anything else? The business case behind this question is to maintain the standard structure of a portal and all sites below it, but let the managers decide who they give access. We are working in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: As per SP Manage Hierarchy mean- Can create sites and edit pages, list items, and documents.

What you mean manage permission in your mind?

Comment: We don't want them to be able to do anything that falls under the "Manage hierarch" permission. Only grant access rights, nothing else.

Comment: You may grant 1. **Read** - Can view pages and list items and download documents. (or)
2. **Restricted Read** - Can view pages and documents, but cannot view historical versions or user permissions.?

Comment: I want to give **only** the following rights to the mangers:
1. contribute: add/change/delete files
2. grant other users contribute rights to their sites. But I don't want them to be able to do any structural changes.

Comment: Create two groups namely Managers and Visitors grant contributor rights to Mangers group and add managers into Managers group. Grant read only permission to visitors group and add visitors users into visitor group.

Comment: And which part in your solution grants the managers rights to grant others permission to their sites?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Navigate to your site.

Step 2: Go to Site Actions ->Site Permissions

Step 3: Click **Stop Inheriting Permissions** button.

Step 4: Remove all the groups

Step 5: Create Group named managerUser using **Create Group** button from ribbon. Check `Contribute` option in **Give Group permission to this site** section

Step 6: Create Group named VistorUser using Create Group button from ribbon. Check `Read` or `View Only` option in **Give Group permission to this site** section

Step 7: Finally add users into appropriate groups.

Comment: Please read my case again.
I want to stay out of the authorization process and let the managers grant other users access to their sites.

Comment: Ask managers to add those users into VistorsUser Group.

Comment: And the managers in the managerUser group (that has contribute rights based on your description) will be able to add users to another group?